# PHP using a Guzzler client between methods

Tags: php, guzzle, behat

I'm rather new to PHP . I was asked to convert some of my tests from Java to PHP to comply with what a client is asking.

So I started with the basic tests (API), and decided to use Guzzler and Behat to make things easier. The problem is that I can't seem to use the same client for all my tests, which is most likely due to the fact that I have no idea what I'm doing in PHP

Here's a snippet that I'm trying to get working:

```
<?php

use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\Testwork\Hook\Scope\BeforeSuiteScope;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;


class FeatureContext implements Context
{

/**
 * @BeforeSuite
 */
public static function prepare(BeforeSuiteScope $scope)
{
    // Setup of Guzzle for API calls
    $client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://test.stxgrp.com.ar']);
}

/**
 * @Then the response status code should be :arg1
 */
public function theResponseStatusCodeShouldBe($arg1)
{
    //Going to make an assert
}

/**
 * @When /^I issue a GET request at url (.*)\/(.*)$/
 */
public function iIssueAGETRequestAtUrl1($PROVIDER_NAME, $PROVIDER_PLACE_ID)
{
    $response = $client->request('GET', '$PROVIDER_NAME.$PROVIDER_PLACE_ID');
}

}
```

The issue I'm having is that inside the method iIssueA.... , the variable $client is not being recognized (I need to use the same client that is setup in the prepare function).

Comment: Have you tried to have the client as a class variable? and call it with $this->client

Comment: I think [Testing a Basic Auth symfony API with behat3](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/l41o/testing-a-basic-auth-symfony-api-with-behat3), [Api request response testing with behat v2 includes json, xml, html and cli](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/ajqn/api-request-response-testing-with-behat-v2-includes-json-xml-html-and-cli) and [Api request response testing with behat v1](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/xw1v/api-request-response-testing-with-behat-v1) would be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can have something like this:

```
    private $client;

/**
 * @BeforeSuite
 */
public function prepare(BeforeSuiteScope $scope)
{
    // Setup of Guzzle for API calls
    $this->client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://test.stxgrp.com.ar']);
}

/**
 * @When /^I issue a GET request at url (.*)\/(.*)$/
 */
public function iIssueAGETRequestAtUrl1($PROVIDER_NAME, $PROVIDER_PLACE_ID)
{
    $this->client->request('GET', '$PROVIDER_NAME.$PROVIDER_PLACE_ID');
}
```

in order to use `$this` you need to remove `static` from `prepare` method.